# Promesa siempre rechaza api rest nodejs mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, api, rest, npm

Hola tengo un problema con mi ruta DELETE en una api rest que estoy haciendo usando node.js con express y usando el paquete NPM mysql, el problema es, que siempre me rechaza la promesa después de realizar el query sql, he probado tratando de borrar usuarios, y si se borran exitosamente pero aun así la promesa entra en el reject

Aquí es donde tengo la función de eliminar en mi modelo Usuario

```
eliminar(id) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            conexion.query(`UPDATE USUARIOS SET ACTIVO = 'NO' WHERE ID = ?`,

                [id],

                (err, res) => {
                    console.log(err);

                    if (err) {
                        reject(err);
                    } else {
                        resolve(res);
                    }
                });
        });
    }
```

Y aquí es donde la mando a llamar

```
usuariosModel
        .eliminar(req.params.id)
        .then(res => {
            return res.status(200).json({
                ok: true,
                data: {
                    msg: `Usuario ID: ${req.params.id} eliminado exitosamente`,
                    ruta: "/usuarios/:id",
                    metodo: "delete"
                }
            });
        })
        .catch(err => {
            return res.status(500).json({
                ok: false,
                data: {
                    msg: "error al eliminar usuario",
                    ruta: "/usuarios/:id",
                    metodo: "delete",
                    err
                }
            });
        });
```

[image: Imagen]

Comment: que imprime `console.log(err);`

Comment: @sioesi devuelve, null

Comment: puedes agregar un pantallazo o texto de lo que responde la consola cuando ejecutas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error es que estas pisando la variable `res` cuando intentas recibir el resultado de `eliminar(req.params.id)`

Esto provoca que `res.status(200)` tire una excepción y salte el `catch`.

### Solución:

Cambiar el nombre del parámetro definido en el `then`

```
usuariosModel
  .eliminar(req.params.id)
  // AQUI
  .then(result => {
    return res.status(200).json({
      ok: true,
      data: {
        msg: `Usuario ID: ${req.params.id} eliminado exitosamente`,
        ruta: "/usuarios/:id",
        metodo: "delete"
      }
    });
  })
```